# Meaning of a halfword and a word in microprocessor

Tags: memory

I'm taking a microprocessor class and I'm a bit confused on the value of a halfword and word. In lectures, my professor keeps referring to a halfword or a word as though it's a fixed value, like Pi.

My understanding (if correct) is the value depends on the processor, 32bits, 64 bits, etc.. So, for a 32bit processor, a halfword would be 18bits. Would someone clarify this?

Comment: "Word" is a confusing and overloaded term. Sometimes it means "the width of the address bus", sometimes "the width of the registers", sometimes "the width of instruction operands", sometimes "16 bits regardless of architecture properties because I only know x86", all depending on who's speaking.  If you don't know which definition your professor has chosen, don't be afraid to ask. Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) has a hard time pinning it down.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter noted, "word" is a loaded term. Now a days, processors have standardized on processors that use powers of as their "word" size (16, 32, 64, 128). This is why we talk in terms of bytes.

1) This was not so in ye olde days. The PDP-8 was a 12-bit processor. Sperry and the DEC TOPS systems were 36-bits. In these cases a "word" the amount of data the processor inherently worked with: in these examples, 12-bits or 36-bits.

2) In on the PDP-11 and VAX, the term "word" meant 16-bits (even though the VAX was a 32-bit processor).

[There may be other "word" meanings I have omitted.]

Thus a word could mean either the amount of data the processor works with or a specific data length. A half word is half of that amount.

You'd really have to ask to find out what your professor means when he says "word."